# Wpf DataGrid ToolTip for column headers

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a tooltip for datagrid cells which is open when cell content is trimmed:

```
    private void grid2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

        while ((dep != null) &&
                !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGrid))
        {
            if (dep is Run)
                continue;

            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep == null)
            return;

        if (dep is DataGridCell)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
            var x = cell.Content as TextBlock;

            if (x.Text != check)
                tlp.IsOpen = false;

            if (x != null)
            {
                FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(x.Text,
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(x.FontFamily.ToString()),
                x.FontSize,
                Brushes.Black);

                if (formattedText.Width > Convert.ToDouble(cell.Column.ActualWidth.ToString()) - 3)
                {
                    tlp.Content = x.Text;
                    tlp.IsOpen = true;
                    check = x.Text;
                }
            }
        }

        if (dep is DataGrid)
            if (tlp.IsOpen == true)
                tlp.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

I want to do the same for column headers, but i don't know how. There is no such object like "DataGridColumnHeader" for example...
Help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i finded a solution. I just replaced ContentPresenter with my textblock with custom tooltip in default DataGridHeader style:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource trimmedVisibilityConverter}}">
            <ToolTip.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </ToolTip.Content>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

And converter:

```
public class TrimmedTextBlockVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;

        FrameworkElement textBlock = (FrameworkElement)value;

        textBlock.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

        if (((FrameworkElement)value).ActualWidth < ((FrameworkElement)value).DesiredSize.Width)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I don't know it is good solution or not, but it works exactly like i need...
Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways for adding a tooltip to a column header.

```xml
    <DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test">
                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                This is a Tooltip
                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test2" MousEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

```cs
    // mouse enter handler
    private void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       var column = TheDataGrid.Columns[1];

       var header = column.Header as TextBlock;

       if (headerIsTrimmed ...) // your logic to check for trim
       {
         header.ToolTip = "This is another Tooltip";
       }
       else
       {
         header.ToolTip = null;
       }
    }
```

Notice the two DataGridTextColumns, for the first I set the tooltip directly. But note that you have to set a TextBlock as the Header, where you can define the tooltip in XAML.
On the second DataGridTextColum I also set the Header as a TextBlock, so that in code-behind or an event handler the tooltip can be added to the TextBlock and so the column header.

EDIT: I added an event handler to the MouseEnter event on the TextBlock that is used as a Header (the second one) there you can place your logic to set the Tooltip to a string if you detect a trimming or set it to null if not.

Comment: Maybe i'm not fully understand your answer, or my question is not completely correct, but i want to know - how can i determine that mouse is over column header?

Comment: @Сиволапый you don't need to manually check for mouse over, as the Tooltip functionality does this for you automatically - just assign the text to it

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks, but it's a little not what i want. I want ToolTip when column header text is trimmed...

Comment: @Сиволапый the Tooltip should work regardless of the size of the column, as long as it is still visible - doesn't it work for you like that?

Comment: @Nicolas It appears even if the column is much wider than the column header.

Comment: I need tooltip, only when column width less then header text width.

Comment: @Сиволапый what is the problem of the tooltip showing always? does it hurt? if yes, I would suggest to catch the column width resize and couple or decouple the tooltip there...

Comment: @Сиволапый if you want to detect when the mouse is over the header like you wrote in your first comment, you can just use the MouseEnter event of the TextBlock you put inside the header (as shown in my answer, I also added the event in an edit)

Comment: @Alex Some parts of my code use column headers. If i puting textblock inside the header, those parts of code stop working... I don't know why...

Comment: @Nicolas I tried it this way, it works not so nice like in my solution :)